# Entity Framework: Running code before all migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I want to migrate stored procedures and views in my DB. Since I always migrate to the latest version, a source-control-friendly approach is to drop/recreate all procedures/views during migration process (with this approach there is one file per procedure, instead of one-per-version).

Since old procedures/functions/views might not be compatible with new schema changes, I want to do drop before all migrations, then do the create after all.

Previously I used a customized FluentMigrator, but now I am researching Entity Framework Code First Migrations. I see that I can use `Seed` to always run code after all migrations.

Is there something I can use to always run code *before* all migrations?

Comment: Now guess why serious projects stay as war away from EF migrations as possible. They. Do. Not. Work. - except in the most simplistic cases. Wait until your need a multi stage migration wih server side data transformations - then the fun starts. Not worth doing it in EF. I always use an external set of SQL change files.

Comment: @TomTom I have only used them a little so far, but I don't see much I could do with FluentMigrator, but can't do here. External SQL is not an option for me as even a trivial regex transform would turn into a huge pain. Though now that I think of it they might be using the same delayed model that does not allow proper mixing of code and SQL. I need to research.

Answer (score 2):

If you want some code to run before migrations kick in, you can specify a custom database initializer:

```
public class AwesomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class AwesomeDbContext : DbContext
{
    static AwesomeDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new AwesomeDatabaseInitializer());
    }

    public IDbSet<AwesomeEntity> Entities { get; set; }
}

public class AwesomeDatabaseInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AwesomeDbContext, AwesomeMigrationsConfiguration>
{
    public override void InitializeDatabase(AwesomeDbContext context)
    {
        // TODO: Run code before migration here...

        base.InitializeDatabase(context);
    }
}

public class AwesomeMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<AwesomeDbContext>
{
    public AwesomeMigrationsConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(AwesomeDbContext context)
    {
        // TODO: Seed database here...
    }
}
```

This sets the custom initializer to a custom `AwesomeDatabaseInitializer`, which inherits from `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`. If you want to drop and rebuild the database every time, you should use the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` as base class instead, though I'm not sure this lets you run migrations.

In the initializer, you can override the `InitializeDatabase` method, where you can run code before you call `base.InitializeDatabase`, which will trigger the database initialization and in turn the `Seed` method of the migration configuration, `AwesomeMigrationsConfiguration`.

This is using EF6. I'm not sure if there is an equivalent in earlier versions of entity framework.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it does not seem to work for migrate.exe (custom initializer is not used, and in fact I am not sure an initializer is used at all).

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution that is pretty horrible, but works for migrate.exe.

Here is the idea:

1. Use Seed for AfterAll, as suggested by [@khellang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/682105/khellang).
2. For BeforeAll, register a custom `IDbConnectionInterceptor` in MigrationsConfiguration constuctor to capture first connection after the MigrationsConfiguration has been created, then make it unregister itself. Obviously this is *absolutely* not thread-safe and only OK in application startup or migrate.exe.

Example code:

```
public class DbMigrationsInterceptingConfiguration<TContext> : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> 
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public DbMigrationsInterceptingConfiguration() {
        BeforeFirstConnectionInterceptor.InterceptNext();
    }

    protected override void Seed(TContext context) {
        Console.WriteLine("After All!");
    }
}

internal class BeforeFirstConnectionInterceptor : IDbConnectionInterceptor {
    public static void InterceptNext() {
        DbInterception.Add(new BeforeFirstConnectionInterceptor());
    }

    public void Opened(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext) {
        // NOT thread safe

        Console.WriteLine("Before All!");
        DbInterception.Remove(this);
    }

    // ... empty implementation of other methods in IDbConnectionInterceptor
 }
```

I am not sure I would be actually using it though.